# Function not printing anything

Tags: python

I wrote this code to print how many prime numbers there are in a given list of numbers,
but it is not outputting anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
def count_primes(nums):
    primes = 0
    number_of_primes = 0
    a_list = []
    listing = 0
    
    a_list == nums
    for x in a_list:
        if a_list % 2 == 0:
            primes = primes + a_list
            listing == len(primes)
            print(listing)
```

Comment: You have to actually call the function, or there was no point in defining it.

Comment: did you mean `if x % 2 == 0:`? Also `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment: `a_list = nums`.

Comment: What's the type of `nums`? Is it the input number? If yes, you cannot assign it to `a_list` then loop overs the list's elements, but if not, what is this number?

Comment: please post example-input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't called the function which is why you're not getting an output.

You may try this code to print the prime numbers at a given range.

```
from math import sqrt

def isPrime(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    if x < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(x))+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if isPrime(i):
        print(i, end=" ")
```